# How to set Created and Modified in PdfExportOptions. DevExpress

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I am using DevExpress PdfExportOptions to set Password permission.
So PDF cannot be commented or edited.
Problem is that when I am using PermissionPassword and using ExportToPDF option.
All security features are working as per my requirement. 
But Created and Modified field is showing empty.

Below is my code for adding security feature.

```cs
Reports.xrptReport intialReport = new Reports.xrptReport();
initialReport.DataSource  = DataSource;
PdfExportOptions pdfOptions = initialReport.ExportOptions.Pdf;
pdfOptions.Compressed = true;  
pdfOptions.ImageQuality = PdfJpegImageQuality.Highest;
pdfOptions.DocumentOptions.Author = "AuthorName";
pdfOptions.DocumentOptions.Title = "Title";
pdfOptions.PasswordSecurityOptions.PermissionsPassword = "password";
pdfOptions.PasswordSecurityOptions.PermissionsOptions.ChangingPermissions = ChangingPermissions.None;
pdfOptions.PasswordSecurityOptions.PermissionsOptions.PrintingPermissions = PrintingPermissions.HighResolution;
intialReport.ExportToPdf(path,pdfOptions);
```

When I am adding this security features Created Date value does not show.
Please help me as I also want to show Created date in Description tab.

Comment: in my case exactly your code is working fine